# Avoid ambiguous partial specialization

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following templates :

```
template<typename T, typename S=void>
struct Array;

template<typename T, int N0, int N1, int S0, int S1>
struct Array<T[N0][N1], T[S0][S1]> {};

template<typename T, int N0, int N1>
struct Array<T[N0][N1], void> : Array<T[N0][N1], T[N1][1]> {};

template<typename T, int N0, int N1, int N2, int S0, int S1, int S2>
struct Array<T[N0][N1][N2], T[S0][S1][S2]> {

  template<int B0, int E0, int B1, int E1, int B2, int E2>
  Array<T[E0 - B0][E1 - B1][E2 - B2], T[S0][S1][S2]>
  get() {
    return Array<T[E0 - B0][E1 - B1][E2 - B2], T[S0][S1][S2]>();
  }
};

template<typename T, int N0, int N1, int N2>
struct Array<T[N0][N1][N2], void> : Array<T[N0][N1][N2], T[N1 * N2][N2][1]> {};

int main() {
  Array<float[3][4][4], float[16][4][1]> a;

  auto b = a.get<0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1>();
  return 0;
}
```

I get the following error because of ambiguous partial specializations of templates :

```
$ clang++ -std=c++11 main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp:26:14: error: ambiguous partial specializations of 'Array<float [2][2][1],     float [16][4][1]>'
  auto b = a.get<0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1>();
         ^
main.cpp:5:8: note: partial specialization matches [with T = float [1], N0 = 2, N1 = 2, S0 = 16, S1 = 4]
struct Array<T[N0][N1], T[S0][S1]> {};
       ^
main.cpp:11:8: note: partial specialization matches [with T = float, N0 = 2, N1 = 2, N2 = 1, S0 = 16, S1 = 4, S2 = 1]
struct Array<T[N0][N1][N2], T[S0][S1][S2]> {
       ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way that I can avoid this ambiguity? In other words, I want the Array templates to be valid only when T is of a non-array type.

Comment: Is it viable to split the 3d and 4d arrays: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259faf3f5410b9bb ?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I'd rather avoid the name explosion, one per array dimension.

Answer (score 4):

It might be overkill, but you could force `T` not to be an array:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename S = void, typename Dummy = void>
struct Array;

template<typename T, int N0, int N1, int S0, int S1>
struct Array<T[N0][N1],
             T[S0][S1],
             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<T>::value>::type>
{ };

template<typename T, int N0, int N1>
struct Array<T[N0][N1],
             void,
             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<T>::value>::type>
: Array<T[N0][N1], T[N1][1]>
{ };

template<typename T, int N0, int N1, int N2, int S0, int S1, int S2>
struct Array<T[N0][N1][N2],
             T[S0][S1][S2],
             typename std::enable_if<!std::is_array<T>::value>::type>
{
    template<int B0, int E0, int B1, int E1, int B2, int E2>
    Array<T[E0 - B0][E1 - B1][E2 - B2], T[S0][S1][S2]>
    get()
    {
        return {};
    }
};
```

If you actually do want to permit array types for `T`, you need to work on it a bit more.

Comment: +1 I still don't completely understand the `= void` trick. Will the user of the template have to explicitly provide `void` to instantiate the specialization that takes it as a second parameter?

Comment: @0x499602D2: That shouldn't be necessary, since `void` is the default argument...

Comment: I don't understand why this ambiguity occurs in the first place. If I change to `auto b = a.get<0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2>();`, there is no ambiguity. Note the '2' for the last template argument.

Comment: @keveman: doesn't the error message make that clear? In the original code you could have either a 3-dim array of `float`, or a 2-dim array of `float[1]`...

Comment: If the first dimension is different, attempting to deduce template parameters for the 2d specialization will deduce two different values for `T` (e.g. `float[1]` and `float[2]`), so that specialization gets ignored.

Comment: With `a.get<0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2>();`, I can also have a 3 dimensional array of `float` or a 2 dimensional array of `float[2]`, no?

Comment: @keveman: well, the first and the second array have to be the same, and the second is determined by the class template arguments...